# Haxe: add @:build metadata to all classes in project

Tags: macros, haxe

Is it possible to apply my type building macro to all classes in a project without modifying their code?

I'm trying to implement a debugger based on Haxe macros: basically I inject calls to my function between every expression in every function of the class. Currently I have an interface `IDebuggable` and only code in classes that implement that interface can be stopped at breakpoints.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`haxe.macro.Compiler.addGlobalMetadata()`](http://api.haxe.org/haxe/macro/Compiler.html?#addGlobalMetadata) for this. This can either be done from an [initialization macro](http://haxe.org/manual/macro-initialization.html) or on the command line:

```
--macro addGlobalMetadata('', '@:build(Build.build())')
```

Comment: Is it possible to distinguish between standart or library classes and project classes? Currently I've added this code, but this is ugly:
  
  var module = Context.getLocalModule();
  if (module == 'DebugRuntime'
   || module.indexOf('haxe') == 0
   || module.indexOf('flash') == 0)
   return null;

Comment: You can make use of the `pathFilter` argument.

Comment: Do not see how can I use it. It allows to filter only one prefix. But most projects have a lot of different packages. I think it is possible to filter based on file path and get file path from Context.CurrentPos, but for this I need project source paths.