# Using custom compile metadata to alias @:build

Tags: macros, haxe

I have a macro class (`HashCodeBuilder`) which injects a hashing function to another class. For the injectee class, I need to add `@:build(base.HashCodeBuilder.build())`

but instead I want to use a custom metadata aliasing the `@:build` metadata and pass parameters to my macro, so instead of

```
@:build(base.HashCodeBuilder.build())
```

I want to use

```
@:hashcodebuilder({composeFields:[product.id, vendor.id]})
```

This could be done by using an interface with the `@:build` macro and then adding my custom, compiler metadata to the injectee. However that means extending some `Impl`, but my injectee might already have a superclass. So that's why I cant use that default strategy.

So what's the best way to do this? There isn't a terrible lot of documentation on macros...

```
// TestClass.hx
@:build(base.HashCodeBuilder.build())
class TestClass extends AlreadySomeSuperClass{
    public function new() {

    }
}

//HashCodeBuilder.hx
class HashCodeBuilder{
    public static function build():Array<Field>{
        var fields = Context.getBuildFields();
        var value = NumberTheory.getRandomPrime();
        var pos = Context.currentPos();
        var hashCodeFunc:Function={
            expr: macro return $v{value},
            ret:(macro:UInt),
            args:[],
        };
        var hashCode:Field ={
            name: 'hashCode',
            access: [Access.APublic],
            kind: FieldType.FFun(hashCodeFunc),
            pos:pos,
        };
        fields.push(hashCode);

        return fields;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haxe Custom Metadata to Macro Call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43872908/haxe-custom-metadata-to-macro-call)